# How can I create AWS vpc, subnets, security groups in opscode chef?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, chef-recipe, amazon-vpc

I can create AWS vpc, subnets, security groups, route53 in Ansible easily. But I did not find any good documents to create these same in Chef using predefined modules or plugins. Using knife EC2 plugin I can only launch aws instance but that is also not working properly.

Comment: https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/aws/

Comment: I downloaded this cookbook. But it does not have creation of vpc so we can assign our aws instance to that vpc. And yes this cookbook has custom resources, that we can write as per our requirement.

Comment: We use Troposphere(python library) and terraform to create the AWS resources. 

[VPC creation with Troposphere](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/blob/master/examples/VPC_EC2_Instance_With_Multiple_Dynamic_IPAddresses.py)
and 
[VPC creation with terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/vpc.html)

Let me know if you need in depth concept of those two

Answer (score 3):

There is both the `aws` cookbook mentioned above as well as the rathole that is `chef-provisioning` (though VPC and subnet management is probably out of scope for that but I've never tried so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯).

Overall I would highly recommend using Terraform or SparkleFormation or a similar tool for this, there just isn't as good a user experience to do hardware management through Chef compared to those tools.

Comment: Terraform is a great tool for this, although you should really take care of people messing around with the terraform's status file, since having a not up-to-date one will result in random AWS/Azure resources decommissioning or generation.

I recommend reading [it's documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/remote/index.html) about this topic.